# Transforming a line in $z$ plane to a circle in $w$ plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following questions:

[image]

For (a) I managed to get $w^2-|w|+2ia|w|w=0$, not sure if this is correct as I'm struggling to show that this represents a circle. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've managed to get (b) by showing that $u^2+(v+\frac{1}{2a})^2=\frac{1}{4a^2}$. However have still not managed to show (b) by continuation of (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for (a) is not correct (a square is missing). We have that $w=\frac{1}{x+iy}$ that is 
$$a=y=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{w}-\frac{1}{\overline{w}}\right)=
\frac{\overline{w}-w}{2i|w|^2}\Leftrightarrow |w|^2+\frac{i(\overline{w}-w)}{2a}=0.
$$
Now, as regards (b), we verify that this is equivalent to $|w+i/(2a)|^2=1/(4a^2)$ (the circle you have to identify) by expanding the product
$$\left|w+\frac{i}{2a}\right|^2=\left(w+\frac{i}{2a}\right)\left(\overline{w}-\frac{i}{2a}\right)=|w|^2+\frac{i(\overline{w}-w)}{2a}+\frac{1}{4a^2}=\frac{1}{4a^2}.$$

Comment: @Luke Taylor Any further doubt?